# universal framework for distribution

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

Hello to all my dear friends, I look for your help once again. I created a personal framework and, following Internet guides, managed to run it simultaneously on both iosSimuletor and device. The problem occurs when, try to create the archive and then send to itunes connect. I pushed this error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). I started out from everything, changed from debug to release, other things found online. But nothing. Do you know what I have to change to the framwork project before I create the square? thank you

Comment: You might want to be more clear / more specific with your question.

Comment: I've created my own framework. When I insert it into an application project, it works fine. Instead, when I create the application project archive, I get the following error:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). So it does not allow me to create the archive and send to itunes connect

Comment: This Tutorial. It allows me to work for iosSimuletor and debugging devices. But no to send to app store  :  https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c

Comment: Uploads to the App Store are just that - apps. Even if you want to upload a keyboard extension, you *still* need to embed it into an app! So why should you expect a framework to be any different? How do you expect it to run? (Think of CocoaPods, which is just another version of "shared code across apps - can you download one through the App Store? No.)

Comment: In the case of the link you posted, *universal* means either (1) it contains embedded files - which any Framework target can do - or (2) it's used across iOS and macOS. That article is pretty old (2014 November) and addresses to iOS developers that they can *finally* add Framework targets that iOS **apps** can use. So at that point @AlexanderMills has a point - what are you trying to do? I have a couple of apps in the App Store that use the same Framework because I want that code (along with some icon images) to be shared across the apps.

Comment: I want to create a framework for my projects or allow other developers to use it. Both for iphoneSimuletor, for iphone debugging and for sending to apple for publication. do you have any advice for me? Some recent tutorials? The thing that interests me and what I have to change in the frameworl project parameters to allow me what I've described above

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it well. I have created my own framework as the tutorial above. I put this framework into an application. The application works well with both the simulator and my device. When I try to create my application's archive to allow it to be sent to itunesConnect, and says: archive failed. And the error: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). I do not want to deploy the framework to the app store but my application within the framework